# Definition of limits in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, definition

Let$$ f: \ D_f \longrightarrow \mathbb{R},$$
where
$$ D_f \subset \mathbb{R}^n, \ n\ge 2.$$
In some materials, it is said that for  function f to have a limit at point $ x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$,
for all positive real numbers d the following has to be true: $$ D_f \cap  \left\{  x\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid 0< \left \Vert x-x_0\right \Vert <d \right\} \ne \varnothing, \ \ x\in \mathbb{R} $$

I wonder if this condition is enough. For example, let
$$ D_f=\left\{(x, y) \mid x\ge 0, y\ge 0 \right\} $$

and $ x_0=(0,0 )$.

Now the condition
$$ \left[0, \infty \right) \times \left[0, \infty \right) \cap  \left\{  x\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid 0< \left \Vert (x,y)-(0,0)\right \Vert <d \right\} \ne \varnothing$$
holds for all $d>0$, but the limit does not exist for sure, since one can not approach the point $(0,0)$ from all directions.

Could someone please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the limit may well exist if $D_f=[0,\infty)\times[0,\infty)$. For instance, if $f\colon[0,\infty)\times[0,\infty)\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ is defined by $f(x,y)=x$, then $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=0$. What this means is that$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0):\|(x,y)\|<\delta\implies\bigl|f(x,y)\bigr|<\varepsilon,$$which is true: for each $\varepsilon>0$, just take $\delta=\varepsilon$.

The condition$$(\forall\delta>0):D_f\cap\{x\in\Bbb R^n\mid\|x-x_0\|<\delta\}\ne\emptyset$$is stated only to make sure that the limit, when it exists, is *unique*. And the existence of a limit at $x_0$ only has to do with what happens when $x$ approaches $x_0$ from some direction *assuming that* $x\in D_f$. So, if $D_f$ is such you cannot approach $x_0$ from some directions, that is not a problem.

Comment: Ok, I think that I have got something wrong with the definition of a limit. Let's consider an easier example. f(x)=x^2, where x is in a closed interval [0, 1]. So when x -> 1 from the left, do we say that f has a limit 1 at x = 1, or it does not have a limit at all? Since it approaches to nothing from the right hand side?

Comment: Since the domain of $f$ is $[0,1]$, $\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)$ are the same thing and $\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)$ makes no sense.